# table view data passes random value to detail view controller in xcode/iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Facing a problem like that, when i click an item on a table view cell to pass the item data to the detail view controller page, its shows another index item detail. can not pass the accurate data. :( is there anybody can help me.

Here is my sample code that I did in didselectrowAtIndexpath method

```
NSString *name = featured.name;
    DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" 
    bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    detail.dname = name;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
    [detail release];
    detail = nil;
```

Comment: what is the data source for your table..is it an array consisting of objects (featured)??'

Comment: yes it is an object containing some data parsed from XML

Answer (score 1):

You must write this code in didselectrowAtIndexpath like

```
 NSString *name = [Myarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
detail.dname = name;
DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" 
bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
[detail release];
detail = nil;
```

**Edit**

```
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
 {
  if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Record"]){
        //
        [passDics setObject:[forgot_pass stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] forKey:@"Forgot_Message"];

        [myarray addObject:passDics
 }
 }
```

Comment: I have tried with it, but here Myarray is not a string array its an object called featured thats why I couldn't call objectAtindex which is not allowed :(

Comment: add xml data in your array using NSDictionary with ObjectForKey

Comment: forgot_pass is a XML node forEx:<forgot_pass>1234</forgot_pass>

Comment: I dont have any problem in parsing, I can parse and then can show the data in a table view. But when I click on the row it doesnt pass the actual data, It sends the previous or next row data to the detail view.